# Adding ADB commands to build sequence (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, adb

I am using Android Studio and wonder if it is possible to add some ADB commands to the build sequence.
Specifically, before the app is installed on my USB-connected device I would like to send a key event to wake the device.
Can the ADB commands that run at the end of the build sequence be customized? Where would these custom commands be entered?

Thanks

Comment: @AgentP "I have this feeling" is not a valid argument, while the whole approach is questionable, because one can a) keep the screen on while `adb` is connected and b) on newer API one doesn't even have to kill anything, but can instead apply the code changes. Stop & relaunch it does nothing else than what you're asking for ...if you don't believe me, just write the Gradle `Exec` task.

Comment: @MartinZeitler Pardon me that was just a fun part..  and please let me know if any alternatives for the lower versions to include the ADB command right before starting the app?  Cause this applying code changes and restarting is always disabled for me due to device limitations.

Comment: @AgentP As stated, one can use an `Exec` task which runs `adb`... then depend on it. It's absolutely no problem to automate that, but I'd still question if there is noticeable timely gain made. Maybe a 1-2 seconds difference, in between first building and then killing it vs. killing it during the build already.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I have no idea how to do that can you drop some links or can you please write an answer? let's forget about killing the process here .. think of any other adb commands that might be useful

Comment: @AgentP  What is the problem statement here? 1. "Waking up the device before the app is installed" or 2. Adding ADB Command to build sequence.  Both are different things. Looks like it is assumed that the solution of the waking up the device will have to be found via the ADB command.

Comment: @SandeepDixit its the second one adding adb command to build sequence

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can create a batch file with the following commands

> gradlew installDebug
>
> adb [whatever you want]

start your activity with this

> am start -n yourpackagename/.activityname

Comment: Can this be incorporated into Android Studio? So that when I click "build" it runs the extra commands before starting the activity?

Answer (score 0):

This is how.
It's You need to adapt your paths and commands.

```
task runAdb(type:Exec) {
    workingDir 'C:\\Users\\[user]\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\platform-tools'
    println 'my custom task runs here'

    //store the output instead of printing to the console:
    //standardOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()

    //add any number of commandLine commands here
    commandLine "cmd","/c",'adb.exe devices'
    commandLine "cmd","/c",'start .'

    //println standardOutput.toString()
}

clean.dependsOn runAdb
```

Another option can be (though I haven't used it ever) to put ADB command in a bat file and add it run/debug configuration> before launch at android studio.

[image]